Cmake not found
can someone help me, I tryed to build my project with kafka, but build drop this error, I used MacBook Pro m3
thread 'main' panicked at /Users/daelon/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cmake-0.1.51/src/lib.rs:1100:5:

failed to execute command: No such file or directory (os error 2)
is `cmake` not installed?

But I have already installed cmake, also, this what throw command
daelon@MacBook-Pro~ % which cmake
/opt/homebrew/bin/cmake

Also I try to export and make source, thats not help(

Fixed, need uninstall cmake if he installed, then run with flag --cask
brew install cmake --cask
